# Edit Appeal: Removing code superfluous to the question

Tags: discussion

I've recently had [an edit rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15215345). The edit attempted to remove some code that was superfluous to the question. Specifically, the code was about problems with a 3D plot in matplotlib, but the user left some code they used for a 2D plot. I removed the 2D plot code and added some other improvements.

Was the edit rejected because:

1. Such a large change should not be made without consulting the user first
2. My edit description was not verbose enough
3. Some other reason

Comment: Editing (fixing) code in questions is frowned upon.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ would you mind linking to a previous post that discusses this, to save you the effort of having to explain it to me again.

Comment: [When should I make edits to code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/812149). TL;DR Be **extremely** careful when editing code in questions, it may inadvertently remove the problem the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing unrelated code is not the only thing you did. You also:

- removed a link
- changed the imports,
- modified the 3D-rendering code,
- removed the code that shows how the example image was created

The comment "Improved formatting and reduced minimal working example" provides only justification for some of this changes, but not for link removal or why you changed the imports. If I see such an edit I also reject it, because it is unclear why it was made and whether it will introduce new problems or not.